# How do I configure Lambda with a VPC to access OpenSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, opensearch

I am trying to create a simple pipeline to index S3 documents using OpenSearch. The S3 trigger part is straightforward but I cannot figure out connecting the Lambda to OpenSearch. I have done the following:

`OpenSearch => configured inside the default VPC using the default SG`

Then for the lambda:

`Lambda => configured inside the default VPC using a separate 'lambda-sg' SG`

I have then allowed all traffic all ports into the default SG from lambda-sg.

Despite numerous tweaks (including using the default sg for both the lambda and OpenSearch), **I get the lambda timing out as it hangs trying to access OpenSearch.**

I have taken identical code onto an EC2 instance with a launch-wizard SG connected to the default SG and the code works perfectly.

Looking into DNS resolving -- if I use the IP on the EC2 instance, I get an SSL error, however with the lambda, it still hangs, which makes me think it's not a DNS issue.

There's numerous poor workarounds for this (public internet access, etc) from hours of research this afternoon, but I'm hoping someone knows the correct way to do this.

Comment: Are both the successful EC2 instance and the failing Lambda function DNS-resolving the OpenSearch cluster endpoint to a local IP address (within the VPC)? PS I wouldn't use the default VPC for this kind of thing as it will cause problems down the road. Are both EC2 and Lambda in the same (private) subnet?

Comment: Thanks @jarmod. I wasn't sure about the DNS resolving so I tried the IP directly. On the EC2 instance I get an SSL error but it still hangs on the lambda, making me think it's not DNS. Yes they're the same subnet.

Answer (score 0):

Closure, for me at least: in the end I gave up on getting OpenSearch working in a VPC.

I went with the workaround to create a cluster outside of the VPC with a public IP. That worked without any issues (apart from security).

This is a good video (and some code snippets) on how to do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=06a3NJwM1VU

This reference may also be useful, as I believe (separate to VPC access), I had issues of access control conflicts:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/fgac.html

Comment: I have to think that private in-VPC access is supported from Lambda but it's not obvious why it's not working for you. Be sure to secure your search endpoint as much as possible because [hackers are quick to find exposed search servers](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/hackers-are-quick-to-notice-exposed-elasticsearch-servers/). Hopefully someone will update here with more help on the underlying issue.